# ECONNREFUSED while running tests on GitHub Actions pipeline via msw

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, vitest, msw

I'm currently having react project which contains some unit, integrations tests. I'm using `msw` for mocking data and hosting mock handlers. It works without any issue on local.

**Problem**:
I'm having testing step in my GitHub Actions pipeline, not having any error or fails (as far I can see from logs) but I'm receiving errors logs of connection failure while not having any issue like this on my local. I suspect it is server connection, but can't figure out what should I do fix this.

Such as:

```
stderr | unknown test
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5678
    at Object.dispatchError (/runner/_work/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:63:19)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/runner/_work/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/runner/_work/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:404:14)
    at Request.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/runner/_work/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/http-request.js:127:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8) undefined
```

My test setup:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'warn' });
});

afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers();
});

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
  vi.restoreAllMocks();
});

configure({ asyncUtilTimeout: 10000 });
```

GitHub Actions workflow for test:

```
...
steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v3

   - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
     with:
       node-version: '16.13.0'

   - name: Setup yarn
     run: npm install -g yarn


   - name: Install dependencies
     run: yarn install

   - id: run-tests
     name: Run tests
     run: yarn test:coverage-ci
  ...
```

Script basically is:

```
test:coverage-ci: "vitest run --coverage.enabled --coverage.reporter='text-summary'"
```

Comment: Could you please provide your request handlers and how you construct `server`? The error stack looks like MSW isn't running during your test at all. The error  itself can also mean that there's no matching request handler for the request you're making (quite a strange port you've got).